# Is there a way to generate an environment key for Rails without running the edit credential file command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am aware that you can run `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit --environment production` to create a `production.key` and a `production.yml.enc` file at the same time. My question is, can you do the something without invoking the `:edit` part?

**What I tried**

I tried `rails credentials:show --environment production` but, if there are no files created yet you get the error:

`Missing 'config/credentials/production.key' to decrypt credentials. See bin/rails credentials:help`

**Why I ask**

Truly I have always just ran the edit code to create the files and then closed out of the file. Easy and fast. But, I am running into a problem now at work with this.

I am creating a template that we can use to quickly and easily make a RoR app from scratch that has all of our standard code. IE, it has the base Stylesheets, JS files, login abilities, etc. I would like the template to also auto-create the `production.key` and `production.yml.enc` files. The actual credentials file can be blank. That's fine.

If I have the template run the command with `edit` then it will wait there until the user closes the credentials file. I would prefer that it just create the files and continue on without needing user input.

Any help that can be given would be most welcome. Thank you.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I'm just spitballing but couldn't you just use a non-interactive editor like `sed` for the `editor` option? Rails doesn't actually have a task to just generate the keys. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89bd41201a060e8e6ee39591430d136e9e012c34/railties/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb

Comment: Did you try just `File.write('config/credentials/production.key', SecureRandom.hex(16))`?

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. mechnicov, I did not try the `SecreRandom.hex(16)` as I was thinking I would have to add a library to be able to create a random string. But, you are right, I wouldn't have to. This is good to know for the future. I am going to go with the answer from @max though as that creates both files for me without user input. I did not know about the `sed` editor. Again, thank you both! max if you want to post your answer, I will mark it!

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself.

Comment: Will do! Thank you @max. I have added the Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Use `sed` editor like so: `run "EDITOR=sed rails credentials:edit --environment production"`

**CONTEXT:**

Per the comment from @max, I was able to get what I needed by using the `sed` editor, a non-interactivce editor I was unfamiliar with.

So, I was able to put `run "EDITOR=sed rails credentials:edit --environment production"` in my template creator, and it created the `production.key` and `production.yml.enc` files I was wanting, without needing to wait for user input to continue.

Thank you @max!

Happy Coding everyone!